# MySQL Affected Rows - Help

Tags: php, mysql, rows

When I try to run this:

```
$s=mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum_topics (forum_id,userid,title,createtime,createip,last_post_user,last_post_userid,last_post_time) VALUES ('$forum_cat_id','$userid','$title','$time','$ip','{$userdata['username']}','$userid','$time')");
        if(mysql_affected_rows($s) == 0)
            return 7;
```

I get the following error: Warning:

```
mysql_affected_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in "PATH/TO/FILE" on line 76
```

Why is that?

**EDIT:** (After I did the var_dump, it returned this):

```
bool(true) string(0) "" Warning: mysql_affected_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in "PATH/TO/SITE" on line 77
```

Comment: `var_dump($s); var_dump(mysql_error());` --- put it right after your `$s = ...` line

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass `$s` into [mysql_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function

Comment: Then it returns this error:
Notice: Use of undefined constant mysql_affected_rows - assumed 'mysql_affected_rows' in

Answer (score 1):

try without paassing nothing  to mysq_affected_rows()

```
$s=mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum_topics (forum_id,userid,title,createtime,createip,last_post_user,last_post_userid,last_post_time) VALUES ('$forum_cat_id','$userid','$title','$time','$ip','{$userdata['username']}','$userid','$time')");
        if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0)

    return 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error. The most common problem, your query is wrong.

`Example: No of Columns do not match, a field requires '' around it and you are omitting that, you are insert wrong type of data into a field.`

To better trouble shoot, spit out the error from php code using mysql_error() function.

To even trouble shoot it more, assign your query to a variable $query and print out that query. Run that in MySQL and see what error you get.